# How to test a Request Object in EasyMocks?

Tags: java, easymock

I have a method that uses setAttribute on the Request object. I need to test that method to see if the attribute set has the right value. I am using EasyMocks and am new to it. I created a mock request object. But I need some help on how to test the method.
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you created the mock object, you can simply set it up by calling specific methods on it with the expected values. If it needs to return values, you use `EasyMock.expect(...)` to configure those. Once you are ready, you call `EasyMock.replay(...)` to start the testing phase. After the tests you should call `EasyMock.verify(...)` to check that all preconfigured calls have been made with the expected parameters.

See [the documentation](http://easymock.org/EasyMock3_0_Documentation.html) for more details and examples.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Spring MockHttpServletRequest and MockHttpServletResponse classes.

http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/springframework/spring/2.0.4/spring-2.0.4-javadoc.jar!/org/springframework/mock/web/MockHttpServletRequest.html

Comment: I am not using the Spring framework. I am working on the J2EE legacy framework.

Comment: then Peter Torok's answer is the way to go.